# Translation of data only possible in one direction?`

Tags: asp.net, localization, c1-cms

In my C1 backend I have a global data type with 3 fields:

- FieldKey [string]
- FieldContent [string]
- Group [string]

I group the data by the "group" field in the data perspective.

My default language is german. If I create data while being in the "German" mode of the C1 backend, I see the data available for translation when switching to "English".

If on the other hand I create the data in the "English" mode, there is no way to translate it when switching to german, because it doesn't even show up in the data perspective.

Is this intended behaviour? Why can't I translate in both directions? (german->english and vice versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu command "View | Translation ..." let you choose what language to translate from.

The translation features has been designed with the premise that one language is 'primary' and that users translating content typically do so "in bulk".

Comment: Not what I had hoped for, but I guess I have to live with it. ;)